# java Quarterback class

Tags: java, oop

Here's my program, I need to fill in the blank methods and can't figure them out. I'm using JAVA object oriented. Please help, I'm new to this so I'm kind of confused. If someone could just help me out it will be awesome, just a little help is better than none.

Description
For  this  program,  you  are  to  create  a  Quarterback  class.    This  is  a  simple  object  that  represents  a    quarterback    in  the  NFL.  Implement  the  UML  diagram    given  below.  You  may  create  additional  private    methods  that    you    feel    are  necessary    or    helpful  to  implement  this  class.

---

**UML  Diagram:**
Create    a  Quarterback  class    based    on   the    following     UML   diagram.

--    attempts  :  int  The  number  of  passing  attempts  made  by  this  Quarterback.
­--    completions    :  int  The  number  of  passing  completions    made  by  this    Quarterback.
­--    firstName  :  String  This  Quarterback’s  first  name.
­--    interceptions  :    int The  number    of    interceptions  thrown  by  this    Quarterback.
--    lastName  :  String  This  Quarterback’s  last  name.
--    touchdowns  :  int  The  number  of  touchdowns  thrown    by  this    Quarterback
--    yards  :  int  The    number  of  passing  yards  this    Quarterback    has.

- Quarterback    ()  Creates  a  new  Quarterback  object.
- Quarterback    (String    first,      String  last,
  int  completions,      int  attempts,
  int  yards,      int  interceptioiinint int  touchdowns)  Creates  a    new  Quarterback    object  with  the  given  parameters.
- copy()  :  Quarterback  Returns  a  Quarterback  object    whose  properties    are  identical    to  this    Quarterback’s  properties.
- equals(o    :  Object)  :  boolean  Returns  true  if  o  is  a  Quarterback  and  o’s  first  name,  last  name,    attempts,  completions,  yards,  interceptions    and  touchdowns    are  all    equal  to  this  Quarterback’s  corresponding  properties.
- getAttempts()  :  int  Returns  this  Quarterback’s  number  of  passing    attempts.
- getCompletions()  :  int  Returns  this  Quarterback’s  number  of    completions.
- getFirstName()  :  String  Returns  this  Quarterback’s  first  name.
- getInterceptions()  :  int  Returns  this  Quarterback’s  number  of    interceptions.
- getLastName()  :  String  Returns  this  Quarterback’s  last    name
- getRating()  :  double  Returns  this  Quarterback’s  NFL  passer  rating.  The  formula  for  NFL    passer
  rating  can  be  found  at:    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passer_rating.
- getTouchdowns()  :  int  Returns  this    Quarterback’s  number  of  touchdowns
- getYards()  :  int  Returns  this  Quarterback’s  number  of  passing    yards.
- setAttempts(attempts  :  int)  Sets    this    Quarterback’s  attempts  to    attempts.
- setCompletions(completions  :  int)  Sets  this  Quarterback’s  completions  to    completions.
- setFirstName(name  :  String)  Sets  this  Quarterback’s  first  name    to  name.
- setInterceptions(interceptions  :    int)    Sets  this  Quarterback’s  interceptions  to    interceptions.
- setLastName(name  :  String)  Sets  this  Quarterback’s  last  name  to    name.
- setTouchdowns(touchdowns  :  int)  Sets  this  Quarterback’s  touchdowns  to    touchdowns.
- setYards(yards  :  int)  Sets  this  Quarterback’s  yards    to    yards.
- toString()  :  String  Returns  a  String  representation  of  this  Quarterback  consisting  of  the    first  name,  a  space,  the  last  name,  and  this  Quarterback’s  passer    rating    displayed  to  one  decimal.  E.g.,  if  q  is  a  Quarterback  object,    q.toString()  will    return:  “Aaron  Rodgers    123.8”

---

```
/*  
 * Dakota Dao  
 * Quarterback class  
 * march 2011  
 */


package quarterback;

public class Quarterback 
{
    private int attempts;
    private int completions;
    private String firstName;
    private int interceptions;
    private String lastName;
    private int touchdowns;
    private int yards;

    //****************************************************************

    public Quarterback( String firstName, 
                        String lastName, 
                        int completions, 
                        int attempts, 
                        int yards, 
                        int interceptions, 
                        int touchdowns )
    {        
    }

    //*****************************************************************

    public void copy ()
    {
    }

    //*****************************************************************    

    public void equals()
    {    
    }

    //*****************************************************************

    public int getAttempts()
    {
        return this.attempts;
    }

    //*****************************************************************

    public int getCompletions()
    {
        return this.completions;
    }

    //*****************************************************************    
    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return this.firstName; 
    }

    //*****************************************************************        

    public int getInterceptions()
    {
        return this.interceptions;
    }

    //*****************************************************************    

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    //*****************************************************************        

    public void getRating()
    {
    }

    //*****************************************************************        

    public int getTouchdowns()
    {
        return this.touchdowns;
    }

    //*****************************************************************        

    public int getYards()
    {
        return this.yards;
    }

    //*****************************************************************        

    public void setAttempts(int attempts)
    {
        this.attempts = attempts;

    }

    //*****************************************************************        

    public void setCompletions(int completions)
    {
        this.completions = completions;
    }

    //*****************************************************************        

    public void setFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;

    }

    //*****************************************************************        

    public void setInterceptions(int interceptions)
    {
        this.interceptions = interceptions;
    }

    //*****************************************************************        

    public void setLastName(String lastName)
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    //*****************************************************************        

    public void setTouchdowns(int touchdowns)
    {
        this.touchdowns = touchdowns;
    }

    //*****************************************************************        

    public void setYards(int yards)
    {
        this.yards = yards;
    }
    //*****************************************************************        

    public String toString()
    {
    }
}
```

Here's the pre-programmed driver:

```
package quarterback;

public class QBTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a Quarterback
        Quarterback qb = new Quarterback ();

        // Test OK quarterback
        qb.setFirstName("qb");
        qb.setLastName("ok");
        qb.setAttempts(465);
        qb.setCompletions(272);
        qb.setYards(2972);
        qb.setTouchdowns(18);
        qb.setInterceptions(12);
        if ("qb ok 79.6".equals(qb.toString())) {
            System.out.println("Passed OK QB");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed OK QB");
            System.out.println("Expected: qb ok 79.6");
            System.out.println("Got: " + qb);
        }

        // Test max quarterback
        qb.setFirstName("qb");
        qb.setLastName("max");
        qb.setAttempts(100);
        qb.setCompletions(78);
        qb.setYards(1275);
        qb.setTouchdowns(12);
        qb.setInterceptions(0);
        if ("qb max 158.3".equals(qb.toString())) {
            System.out.println("Passed max QB");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed max QB");
            System.out.println("Expected: qb max 158.3");
            System.out.println("Got: " + qb);
        }

        // Test completions too high
        qb.setFirstName("qb");
        qb.setLastName("comp2hi");
        qb.setAttempts(100);
        qb.setCompletions(78);
        qb.setYards(1000);
        qb.setTouchdowns(7);
        qb.setInterceptions(5);
        if ("qb comp2hi 110.8".equals(qb.toString())) {
            System.out.println("Passed completions too high");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed completions too high");
            System.out.println("Expected: qb comp2hi 110.8");
            System.out.println("Got: " + qb);
        }

        // Test completions too low
        qb.setFirstName("qb");
        qb.setLastName("comp2low");
        qb.setAttempts(100);
        qb.setCompletions(25);
        qb.setYards(1000);
        qb.setTouchdowns(7);
        qb.setInterceptions(5);
        if ("qb comp2low 71.3".equals(qb.toString())) {
            System.out.println("Passed completions too low");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed completions too low");
            System.out.println("Expected: qb comp2low 71.3");
            System.out.println("Got: " + qb);
        }

        // Test completions 0
        qb.setFirstName("qb");
        qb.setLastName("comp0");
        qb.setAttempts(100);
        qb.setCompletions(30);
        qb.setYards(1000);
        qb.setTouchdowns(7);
        qb.setInterceptions(5);
        if ("qb comp0 71.3".equals(qb.toString())) {
            System.out.println("Passed completions 0");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed completions 0");
            System.out.println("Expected: qb comp0 71.3");
            System.out.println("Got: " + qb);
        }

        // Test yards too high
        qb.setFirstName("qb");
        qb.setLastName("yards2hi");
        qb.setAttempts(100);
        qb.setCompletions(50);
        qb.setYards(1275);
        qb.setTouchdowns(7);
        qb.setInterceptions(5);
        if ("qb yards2hi 98.3".equals(qb.toString())) {
            System.out.println("Passed yards too high");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed yards too high");
            System.out.println("Expected: qb yards2hi 98.3");
            System.out.println("Got: " + qb);
        }

        // Test yards too low
        qb.setFirstName("qb");
        qb.setLastName("yards2low");
        qb.setAttempts(100);
        qb.setCompletions(50);
        qb.setYards(250);
        qb.setTouchdowns(7);
        qb.setInterceptions(5);
        if ("qb yards2low 58.8".equals(qb.toString())) {
            System.out.println("Passed yards too low");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed yards too low");
            System.out.println("Expected: qb yards2low 58.8");
            System.out.println("Got: " + qb);
        }

        // Test yards 0
        qb.setFirstName("qb");
        qb.setLastName("yards0");
        qb.setAttempts(100);
        qb.setCompletions(50);
        qb.setYards(300);
        qb.setTouchdowns(7);
        qb.setInterceptions(5);
        if ("qb yards0 58.8".equals(qb.toString())) {
            System.out.println("Passed yards 0");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed yards 0");
            System.out.println("Expected: qb yards0 58.8");
            System.out.println("Got: " + qb);
        }

        // Test td too high
        qb.setFirstName("qb");
        qb.setLastName("td2hi");
        qb.setAttempts(100);
        qb.setCompletions(50);
        qb.setYards(1000);
        qb.setTouchdowns(14);
        qb.setInterceptions(5);
        if ("qb td2hi 104.2".equals(qb.toString())) {
            System.out.println("Passed td too high");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed td too high");
            System.out.println("Expected: qb td2hi 104.2");
            System.out.println("Got: " + qb);
        }

        // Test td 0
        qb.setFirstName("qb");
        qb.setLastName("td0");
        qb.setAttempts(100);
        qb.setCompletions(50);
        qb.setYards(1000);
        qb.setTouchdowns(0);
        qb.setInterceptions(5);
        if ("qb td0 64.6".equals(qb.toString())) {
            System.out.println("Passed td 0");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed td 0");
            System.out.println("Expected: qb td0 64.6");
            System.out.println("Got: " + qb);
        }

        // Test int too low
        qb.setFirstName("qb");
        qb.setLastName("int2low");
        qb.setAttempts(100);
        qb.setCompletions(50);
        qb.setYards(1000);
        qb.setTouchdowns(7);
        qb.setInterceptions(11);
        if ("qb int2low 69.2".equals(qb.toString())) {
            System.out.println("Passed int too low");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed int too low");
            System.out.println("Expected: qb int2low 69.2");
            System.out.println("Got: " + qb);
        }

        // Test int 0
        qb.setFirstName("qb");
        qb.setLastName("int0");
        qb.setAttempts(1000);
        qb.setCompletions(500);
        qb.setYards(10000);
        qb.setTouchdowns(70);
        qb.setInterceptions(95);
        if ("qb int0 69.2".equals(qb.toString())) {
            System.out.println("Passed int 0");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed int 0");
            System.out.println("Expected: qb int0 69.2");
            System.out.println("Got: " + qb);
        }

        // Test copy and equals
        Quarterback qbcopy = new Quarterback();
        qbcopy = qb.copy();
        if (qbcopy.equals(qb)) {
            // copy and equals works
            System.out.println("Passed qb copy and equals");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed qb copy and equals");
            System.out.println("Original qb: " + qb);
            System.out.println("Copied qb: " + qbcopy);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks suspiciously like a homework assignment. If you got the homework, you also got the lecture that should've taught you how to do it. Writing the code for you does not help you learning, or your teacher judging your progress.

Comment: ya my teacher said we are allowed to get any help if we dont get it.

Comment: I would attempt to fill the methods yourself first and come back with your errors for help. If you are having problems filling the methods ask specific questions about specific problems.

Comment: You need to ask a **specific** question ... not just "help me!".  Besides, dumping that much code / description in a question is pushing the boundaries of what people are willing to read.

Comment: I suggest trimming it down to something specific that you do not understand would get you more help. I'd love to explain something, even write some code, but i'm not going to do all your work, and I'm not going to guess which function gives you the most trouble. (hmm. aka: what @stephen-c said)

Comment: @Dakota: Note you can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) by indenting them four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. It's been done for you this time, but next time try it yourself. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Comment: ...  As for asking questions, read ["Writing the perfect question"](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) for general advice, ["How to ask and answer homework questions?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) for information specific to homework, ["When asking about code"](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#code) for a little on code in questions and ["The Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example"](http://sscce.org/) for info on how to write code samples.

Answer (score 2):

OK. I'll give you some pointers

For the constructor you need to set the objects properties to the relevant arguments passed in the constructor. Then in the `copy` method since you already have a constructor that takes all the properties you need to call it with the properties of the current object.

For the equals method you compare primitive types with the `==` operator and strings have an [equals](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method to check for string equality.

To write the toString method you need create a string with the relevant properties and spaces between them and return that string.

That should get you started.